# Como evitar registros duplicados en una consulta mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla donde almaceno empresas.
Luego tengo una tabla movimientos donde inserto varios montos efectico/banco y la id de una empresa de la tabla empresa.

Estructura de la tabla Empresa:

```
idCuCorriente |     nBanco      |  
---+--------------+-----------------
1             | Banco 1         |
2             | Banco 2         | 
3             | Banco 3         |
```

Estructura de la tabla Movimiento

```
idCaja |  idCuCorriente |  mov_efectivo |  saldo_efectivo   |  mov_banco   |  saldo_banco   |  
    ---+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1  | 1              | 1,0000        | 1,0000            | 0.00         | 0.00
    2  | 2              | 0.00          | 0.00              | 500.00       | 500.00
    3  | 2              | 0.00          | 0.00              | 400.00       | 400.00
```

Lo que quiero listar es el registro mas reciente de cada empresa (idCuCorriente)
El resultado me tendria que salir asi :

```
idCaja |  idCuCorriente |  mov_efectivo |  saldo_efectivo   |  mov_banco   |  saldo_banco   |  
    ---+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1  | 1              | 1,0000        | 1,0000            | 0.00         | 0.00
    3  | 2              | 0.00          | 0.00              | 400.00       | 400.00
```

¿Como puedo hacer el SELECT para que salga este resultado?

Comment: Tengo una duda, en la tabla movimiento no guardas la fecha de cuando se hizo cada una de las transacciónes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo principal de tu consulta es obtener el último movimiento de cada `idCuCorriente`, por los datos que muestras, entiendo que la forma es mirar el último `idCaja`, por lo que esto sería algo así:

```
SELECT  idCuCorriente,
        MAX(idCaja) idCaja
        FROM Movimiento
        GROUP BY idCuCorriente
```

Ahora, sabiendo cual es el último movimiento, podemos incorporar esto como subconsulta:

```
SELECT  M.idCaja,
        M.idCuCorriente,
        M.mov_efectivo,
        M.saldo_efectivo,
        M.mov_banco,
        M.saldo_banco
    FROM Empresa E
    INNER JOIN (SELECT  idCuCorriente,
                MAX(idCaja) idCaja
            FROM Movimiento
            GROUP BY idCuCorriente
        ) U
        ON U.idCuCorriente = E.idCuCorriente
    INNER JOIN Movimiento M
        ON M.idCuCorriente = U.idCuCorriente
        AND M.idCaja = U.idCaja
```

Algunos comentarios adicionales:

- Estrictamente hablando, no son duplicados las filas que deseas quitar
- Usar un `Id` que sea incremental en el tiempo ya sea por ser un autonumérico o por que se mantiene desde el sistema es una forma rápida de obtener el último registro, pero si queremos ser puristas, un `id` no debería indicar esta temporalidad de las filas, lo debiera hacer una fecha, en cuyo caso la consulta es similar pero un poco más compleja, ya que habría que calcular la fecha máxima y recién ahí ir a buscar el `id`.
- Esta solución es bastante "ansi SQL", posiblemente existan mejores alternativas para MySql.

Comment: Yo venia a ofrecer otra respuesta alternativa pero esta me termino ayudando con otra consulta y me redujo los tiempos de busqueda un 30% o sea que ya para mi es mejor alternativa a todas las que estaba usando.

Answer (score 1):

no sabría como traer solamente la ultima actualización por que no estas guardando una fecha ni nada donde pueda saber cual fue la ultima inserción, no sabría si el IDCaja me serviría...

Pero para comenzar podes probar con esto:

SELECT DISCTINT *
FROM Movimiento
NATURAL JOIN Empresa;

Ahora podemos empezar a editar la respuesta hasta llegar a la concreta.